# Use custom lexer with jparsec

Tags: java, jparsec

I am writing a parser for a language that has very complex lexer rules. For example, the lexer decision depends on the column at which a token appears. I wanted to use `jparsec`, but I can't use its internal tokenizer mechanism. Thus, I need to use my own tokenizer, that generates `jparsec` token.

Unfortunately, I can't find how to write code to 'give' these tokens to `jparsec` to do only the parsing phase.

There is already a Stack Overflow question related to this subject, but the provided solution was to use `jparsec` tokenizer mechanism and I really can't.

I tried different approach, like using the `from` method of the Parser class. But without success. Does anybody know how to use `jparsec` only for the parsing phase and not the lexing one?

Comment: I never used jparsec, but in ANTLR the tokenizer delivers the source location of the token so the parser can make use of that information to understand. The problem would not be to use a custom lexer here. Have you tried using https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec/blob/master/jparsec/src/main/java/org/jparsec/Token.java#L48?